# Cant get format function to work in python

Tags: python, printing, format

When I run the following code, it never adds the spacing like it should between the words.

```
print("{:<5}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}{:>10}".format("President", "First Month", "Last Month", "Difference", "Percentage"))
```

Any help is appreciated!

Comment: As a good habit, please show your desired output.

Comment: yes... include some output please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The number is the entire space available, if it's less than the length of the word it won't work. Try

```
>>> print("{:<30}{:>30}{:>30}{:>30}{:>30}".format("President", "First Month", "Last Month", "Difference", "Percentage"))
President                                        First Month                    Last Month                    Difference                    Percentage
```

Edit those numbers according to your visual needs

Answer (score 0):

I think this will work

```
print("{:<5} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10} {:>10}".format("President", "First Month", "Last Month", "Difference", "Percentage"))
```